# R Sort Header Using Their Value

Tags: r

I have a frequency data calculated by the time of the day:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
 0  1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  2 20 21 22 23  3  4  6  7  8  9 
 5  3  3  7 10 11 13 17 18 14  8  4  2  2  1  4  1  1  3  7  8 11  8
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

The Value 0 means 12:00 pm to 1:00 am, 1 means 1:00am to 2:00am. We can see the headers are sorted randomly and there are some missing value (in this case, 5). I would like R to sort the headers ascendingly. And next step is to find the missing value (like [1,2,3,6,7], the 4 and 5 time periods are missing) and then replace the NA value with 0.

Is there an easy way to complete this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Because R is thoughtfully prepending `X` to each of your column names (because it doesn't like column names starting with numbers), we need to know how to remove them:

```
gsub("X", "", colnames(my.data))
#  [1] "0"  "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "2"  "20" "21"
# [16] "22" "23" "3"  "4"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"
```

(If you use `read.table(..., check.names=FALSE)`, then the column names will be the raw numbers, not requiring the `gsub` step.) With that, we just want to change the order based on the integerization of those strings.

```
my.data[ order(as.integer(gsub("X", "", colnames(my.data)))) ]
#   X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23
# 1  5  3  2  1  3  7  8 11  8   3   7  10  11  13  17  18  14   8   4   2   1   4   1
```

and therefore

```
my.data[ colnames(my.data)[ order(as.integer(gsub("X", "", colnames(my.data)))) ] ]
#   X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23
# 1  5  3  2  1  3  7  8 11  8   3   7  10  11  13  17  18  14   8   4   2   1   4   1
```

---

If you have the ability to change the headers on read-in, then:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
 0  1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  2 20 21 22 23  3  4  6  7  8  9 
 5  3  3  7 10 11 13 17 18 14  8  4  2  2  1  4  1  1  3  7  8 11  8
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA', check.names=FALSE)
my.data
#   0 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 21 22 23 3 4 6 7  8 9
# 1 5 3  3  7 10 11 13 17 18 14  8  4 2  2  1  4  1 1 3 7 8 11 8
my.data[ order(as.integer(colnames(my.data))) ]
#   0 1 2 3 4 6 7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
# 1 5 3 2 1 3 7 8 11 8  3  7 10 11 13 17 18 14  8  4  2  1  4  1
```

(We still need `as.integer` because column names are always returned as `character`.)